# On embedded device how to natively debug a executable generated by bazel build

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, cross-compiling, bazel

Bazel build a simple piece of code hello-world with cross-comipler toolchains.

```
$ cat examples/hello_world/BUILD
cc_binary(
    name = "hello_world",
    srcs = ["hello_world.cpp"],
)
$ bazel build --cxxopt=-std=c++11 --config=tda4 --copt=-DWITH_TDA4 --subcommands --copt=-DFOOFXXX -c dbg --strip=never //examples/hello_world:hello_world
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...

INFO: Analyzed target //examples/hello_world:hello_world (41 packages loaded, 40489 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
SUBCOMMAND: # //examples/hello_world:hello_world [action 'Compiling examples/hello_world/main.cpp', configuration: e23aa3bce872abfb8f06c09952a42b5c1c7714b1c55b5bf022d91a6582852828, execution platform: @local_config_platform//:host]
(cd /home/wss/.cache/bazel/_bazel_wss/4112892ab2eb09dee5980f588ac10e42/execroot/com_minieye_aiplorer && \
  exec env - \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/melodic/lib \
    PATH=/opt/ros/melodic/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
  bazel/toolchain/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/wrappers/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc -MD -MF bazel-out/aarch64-dbg/bin/examples/hello_world/_objs/hello_world/main.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/aarch64-dbg/bin/examples/hello_world/_objs/hello_world/main.o' '-DBAZEL_CURRENT_REPOSITORY=""' -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-dbg/bin -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-dbg/bin/external/bazel_tools '--sysroot=external/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-sysroot' -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -DWITH_TDA4 -DFOOFXXX '-std=c++11' -c examples/hello_world/main.cpp -o bazel-out/aarch64-dbg/bin/examples/hello_world/_objs/hello_world/main.o)
# Configuration: e53aa3bce872abfb8f06c29952a42b5c1c7714b1c55b5bf022d91a6582852828
# Execution platform: @local_config_platform//:host
SUBCOMMAND: # //examples/hello_world:hello_world [action 'Linking examples/hello_world/hello_world', configuration: e23aa3bce872abfb8f06c09952a42b5c1c7714b1c55b5bf022d91a6582852828, execution platform: @local_config_platform//:host]
(cd /home/wss/.cache/bazel/_bazel_wss/4112892ab2eb09dee5980f588ac10e42/execroot/com_minieye_aiplorer && \
  exec env - \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/melodic/lib \
    PATH=/opt/ros/melodic/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
  bazel/toolchain/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/wrappers/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc @bazel-out/aarch64-dbg/bin/examples/hello_world/hello_world-2.params)
# Configuration: e23aa3bce872abfb8f06c09952a42b5c1c7714b1c55b5bf022d91a6582852828
# Execution platform: @local_config_platform//:host
Target //examples/hello_world:hello_world up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/examples/hello_world/hello_world
INFO: Elapsed time: 5.316s, Critical Path: 1.37s
INFO: 6 processes: 4 internal, 2 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 6 total actions
```

`note:`  tda4 is the type of soc on target device, and this parameter
determines which cross-compilation toolchain to be used, I confirm that the generated executable binary contains `.debug_info` section, and the `size is 000288`, and after add the flag --fission=no, the size is the same, because `no` is the default value of fission.

```
$ file bazel-bin/examples/hello_world/hello_world
bazel-bin/examples/hello_world/hello_world: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64,   
version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1,    
for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, with debug_info, not stripped
$ readelf -WS bazel-bin/examples/hello_world/hello_world |grep -E "Address|debug"
[Nr] Name             Type        Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
[26] .debug_aranges   PROGBITS    0000000000000000 0010c0 000110 00      0   0 16
[27] .debug_info      PROGBITS    0000000000000000 0011d0 000288 00      0   0  1
[28] .debug_abbrev    PROGBITS    0000000000000000 001458 00019c 00      0   0  1
[29] .debug_line      PROGBITS    0000000000000000 0015f4 0002d3 00      0   0  1
[30] .debug_str       PROGBITS    0000000000000000 0018c7 000338 01  MS  0   0  1
[31] .debug_loc       PROGBITS    0000000000000000 001bff 00019b 00      0   0  1
[32] .debug_ranges    PROGBITS    0000000000000000 001da0 0000c0 00      0   0 16
```

then scp the executable binary to the target embedded device under the directory /app/bin, and also scp the whole source code directory `examples(sub-directory includes hello_world/hello_world.cpp)` to the device under /app/bin, now run GDB for natively stepping debug, and set the directories of the souce code at first to make sure the gdb will find the source code, but it'll not display the source code still.

```
$ gdb hello_world
Reading symbols from hello_world...
(gdb) set directories /app/bin/examples/hello_world
(gdb) shell cat -n /app/bin/examples/hello_world/hello_world.cpp  |tail -10
     5  int fun(int a, int b)
     6  {
     7     return a+b;
     8  }
     9  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    10    std::cout << "WITH LINUX~~~" << std::endl;
    11    int c=fun(1,1);
    12    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    13    std::cout<<c<<std::endl;
    14    return 0;
    15  }
(gdb) b hello_world.cpp:10
No source file named hello_world.cpp.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (hello_world.cpp:10) pending.
(gdb) b hello_world.cpp:11
No source file named hello_world.cpp.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 2 (hello_world.cpp:11) pending.
(gdb) i b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1       breakpoint     keep y   <PENDING>  hello_world.cpp:10
2       breakpoint     keep y   <PENDING>  hello_world.cpp:11
(gdb) r
Starting program: /app/bin/hello_world
WITH LINUX~~~
Hello World!
2
[Inferior 1 (process 17279) exited normally]
```

We can find the addresses of breakpoints are `pending`, and they can break the program.

Comment: You could try to strip exe and see how much debug is gone. Bet it is not much

Comment: Notice when you create the breakpoint GDB gives an address only, not an address, file, and line number.  This indicates that GDB (for some reason) thinks that `main` is in a location which lacks debug information ... based on the reference to `start.S` GDB for some reason thinks that main is in the startup libraries.  You could try placing a breakpoint base on file/line directly, e.g. `break hello_world.cpp:LINE` -- replace LINE with the line number of a line within your main function.  This shouldn't be needed though, something is going wrong, but lets see if we can find a work around.

Comment: I've updated the question, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> confirm that the generated executable binary contains debug info

> `... with debug_info, not stripped`

This *does not* actually confirm anything useful -- it just says that there is *some* debug info present. But that debug info could be coming from `crt0.o` and not from any of your sources.

Indeed this line:

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x000000000040497c in main ()
```

tells us that you *don't* have debug info for `main`.

You can use `readelf -WS /app/bin/hello_world` and look for the size of the `.debug_info` section. Chances are that size is really small.

---

> Bazel build a simple piece of code hello-world

What command line flags did you use? In particular, did you use `-c dbg`?

If not, that's likely your problem. [Documentation](https://bazel.build/docs/user-manual#compilation-mode).

**Update:**

> `bazel build ... -c dbg  ...`

The only other thing I can think of is to disable [fission](https://bazel.build/docs/user-manual#fission): append `--fission=no` and see if the size of `.debug_info` changes.

**Update 2:**

In the `readelf -wi ...` output, we see that there are only 5 `DW_TAG_compile_unit`s present, and *all* of them are from GLIBC startup files; *none* are from your own application.

This confirms my suspicion -- you *don't* actually have any debug info for your own sources.

But `bazel build -c dbg ...` *should have* produced this debug info. The next step is to use `bazel build --subcommands --copt=-DFOOFXXX=$RANDOM -c dbg ...` to rebuild the app and see what *actual* compile command is being used.

**Update 3:**

The compilation command:

```
bazel/toolchain/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/wrappers/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc \
  -MD -MF \
  bazel-out/aarch64-dbg/bin/examples/hello_world/_objs/hello_world/main.d \
  -frandom-seed=bazel-out/aarch64-dbg/bin/examples/hello_world/_objs/hello_world/main.o \
  -DBAZEL_CURRENT_REPOSITORY="" -iquote . \
  -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-dbg/bin \
  -iquote external/bazel_tools \
  -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-dbg/bin/external/bazel_tools \
  --sysroot=external/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-sysroot \
  -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-canonical-system-headers \
  -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined \
  -D__DATE__="redacted" \
  -D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted" \
  -D__TIME__="redacted" \
  -DWITH_TDA4 -DFOOFXXX -std=c++11 \
  -c examples/hello_world/main.cpp \
  -o bazel-out/aarch64-dbg/bin/examples/hello_world/_objs/hello_world/main.o
```

lacks the `-g` flag, so GCC was never told to emit debug info in the first place.

This means that this toolchain is misconfigured.

I don't know how this happened, but you should be able to work around this by appending an explicit `--copt=-g` flag.

Comment: I've update the question,  it includes more informations, and the command line contains flags -c dbg, and the exetuable binary contains the .debug_info section.

Comment: @wssbygone "the exetuable binary contains the .debug_info section" -- yes, we _aready_ knew that (read the answer again). I've updated the answer.

Comment: @wssbygone I see that you've edited your question (note that such edits are invisible unless I specifically look for them). I _think_ `--fission=no` has to go after `-c dbg` on the command line.

Comment: I try to change the order that  `-c dbg following with --fission=no` according what you said, and edit the question, and the results of readelf -WS 
 bianry  are the latest, the size of .debug_info is also 288.

Comment: @wssbygone I guess for a tiny app like this, the size of `.debug_info` can be that small. When I build your source with `clang++ -g`, I get `.debug_info` of `0x32b`. Can you update your question with the output from `readelf -w /app/bin/hello_world`? That should definitively answer whether you actually have debug info or not.

Comment: You mean all the output from `readelf -w /app/bin/hello_world` ? That'll be to long, and  I've edited the question with the complete info for .debug_info.

Comment: @wssbygone I've updated the answer -- my guess about the root cause has been correct -- you don't have debug info for your sources. But I still don't know _why_ that is happening.

Comment: what's meaning for --copt=-DFOOFXXX=$(RANDOM) ? If I should to replace the $(RANDOM) with a number?   I've updated the  question again.

Comment: @wssbygone `$RANDOM` expands to a random number under `bash`. Try `echo $RANDOM`. I did make a mistake -- the parenthesis around `RANDOM` are wrong. The intent was to force `bazel` to rebuild (by changing the command line). Anyway, it's now clear _what_ is happening (but not _why_). See Update 3.

Comment: thank you for your help,  after appending an explicit --copt=-g flag, It can display the source code now, even though there are some useless log `Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb._execute_unwinders function is missing:`.  And why the flag  `-c dbg` doesn't take effect?